# Temp Table giving Operand Clash error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using a `CASE` statement to help populate a temp table, but for some reason I'm getting an Operand type clash error:

```
CREATE TABLE #users 
  ( 
     id       INT IDENTITY (1, 1), 
     userid   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, 
     username VARCHAR(50),
     sysrole VARCHAR(50) 
  ) 

--Insert all loadtest users into temp table
INSERT INTO #users 
            (userid, 
             username,
             sysrole) 
SELECT id, 
       username,
       sysrole =
       CASE 
            WHEN id between 0 and 100 THEN '63F7971B-45FF-4E3C-86E7-9D0507AF60C0'
            WHEN id between 101 and 200 THEN '26478736-7937-4E52-891B-E80A8D609693'
            WHEN id between 201 and 300 THEN 'CEF5F44F-0961-414C-8578-22BEB0C4B9FF'
            WHEN id between 301 and 400 THEN '63F7971B-45FF-4E3C-86E7-9D0507AF60C0'
            WHEN id between 401 and 500 THEN '7FD13C9E-731B-43AE-95F0-E9AEDC65759C'
        END
FROM   user 
WHERE  username LIKE '%Test%'
```

There are 500 users, so the CASE does handle all those possibilities. However the operand type clash is reading (on the line that the INSERT INTO begins on) `uniqueidentifier is incompatible with tinyint`.

Is the `IDENTITY` column not autopopulating during the `INSERT`?

EDIT: I just realized it would be useful to know what the `user` table looks like. It has about a dozen columns, but the ones I'm wanting to pull from it are:

`id` which is the primary key
`username` which is a string (uniqueidentifier on user)

`sysrole` is getting defined by the `CASE` as you can see.

Comment: It should be, so why are you inserting `id` instead of `userid` into the temp table?!

Comment: Typo. It should be `FROM user`, which is a different table. The PK there is called `id`, not `userid`.

Comment: So if the PK is id, and presumably a tinyint, why are you inserting it into a guid column?  See my answer.  Apologies if I have misunderstood, sight of the `user` schema would help.

Comment: You are inserting `user.id` (which is `TINYINT`) into `users.userid` which is a `uniqueidentifier`.

Comment: Aaron, I updated the code just haven't fixed the code in the example yet. You're the 4th person to point out that (and I am an idiot).

Comment: ypercube - see the updated code. Also user.id is uniqueidentifier and should get inserted into #users.userid.. not sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: This is one strong argument for never naming any column `id` - it is way too vague and it is even confusing you - and you designed the thing! Your code still says `INSERT INTO (GUID column (id)) SELECT GUID column (id) WHERE GUID column (id) BETWEEN 301 AND 400` - this makes no sense!

Comment: If user.id is uniqueidentifier then why on earth does the where clause say `BETWEEN 301 AND 400`? How could that ever be true for a GUID column?

Comment: Good point. I'll rename that column, it is a bit confusing since there are multiple ID columns in play.

Comment: Also that might be the bug, it should be #users.id and not user.id. I'm gonna rename a few of the objects to make it less confusing.

Comment: You can't reference #users.id in the SELECT list of your insert statement. I think you should start over.

Comment: Yeah, I'm noticing that. This is my first time trying to create my own `CASE` statement, so I'm learning as I'm going with that. I'll rethink it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If just you want to assign five string values to 500 users arbitrarily, one to each hundred, you should consider a different approach:

```
WITH enumerated AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    username,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY username)
  FROM user
  WHERE username LIKE '%test%'
)
SELECT
  rn,
  id,
  username,
  sysrole = CASE 
    WHEN rn between 0 and 100 THEN '63F7971B-45FF-4E3C-86E7-9D0507AF60C0'
    WHEN rn between 101 and 200 THEN '26478736-7937-4E52-891B-E80A8D609693'
    WHEN rn between 201 and 300 THEN 'CEF5F44F-0961-414C-8578-22BEB0C4B9FF'
    WHEN rn between 301 and 400 THEN '63F7971B-45FF-4E3C-86E7-9D0507AF60C0'
    WHEN rn between 401 and 500 THEN '7FD13C9E-731B-43AE-95F0-E9AEDC65759C'
  END
FROM enumerated
;
```

The `enumerated` subquery assigns row numbers to the selected rows and the main query uses the numbers to assign `sysrole` values.

And you don't need a temporary table for that specific task.

Comment: That's definitely a far more elegant approach than what I was trying to hack together. I was actually going to refactor the code eventually to try to figure out how to do that approach (I'm still learning some stuff) but was hoping my hacked together query would suffice until I managed to do that. I also never would have considered a CTE (even though it really is the best answer). Thanks for being helpful, and have given me more to read!

Comment: @SeanLong: In this particular case, it could be a "normal" subselect too (`SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ...)`), it just that CTEs are usually more readable. (That may be subjective, though.)

Comment: I think the CTE will work better in the long run. It's going to make it easier to update and read, and this isn't the totality of the code anyway (the reason I initially went with a temp table is because I needed to iterate through each line and use the values in a separate stored procedure). That latter part is definitely something I can work with though, and this makes the `CASE` statement much easier to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I have vague recollections that tinyint only goes up to 127.  You can look it up.  The solution is to change the datatype to smallint.

**Edit**
I looked it up.  I had the right value, but for the wrong database engine.  Solution still applies though.

Comment: Think it goes to 255. Way too small for an identity column, in any case.

Comment: Agree, only tinyint is 0 to 255.

Comment: Good catch. I changed it. Doesn't fix the problem though, the same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

A tinyint datatype is only 1 byte in size, and can only have values between 0 and 255.  An IDENTITY type should use datatype INT.

Comment: Good catch. I changed it, but the error persists. The weird thing is that all of the references to Tinyint have now been removed, even though I made sure to drop the created table and cleared the buffer (to make sure it wasn't sticking in there).

Comment: I just looked at the syntax that is used for Identity columns.  Try this:   [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,  (dont know if the NOT NULL matters or not)